# Getting notified if a dll is added to GAC

Tags: c#, dll, gac

I have an app which is using a dll loaded from the GAC.
If the dll is updated / a new version added, I would like my app to know; so it can load the new version (in an App Domain).

It is possible to ask the OS to notify if a file is added to a watched folder.

**Is it possible to be notified, in a similar way to a folder watch, if a dll is added to the GAC?**